# joi.object for extended class

Tags: extends, joi

I have class User, and class Student which is extends of User.
I wrote schema for the user:

```
    public static validationSchema = Joi.object({
        userID: Joi.number().optional().positive(),
        firstName: Joi.string().required().min(2).max(15),
        lastName: Joi.string().required().min(2).max(15),
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        phone: Joi.string().required().min(10).max(13),
        isWhatsapp: Joi.boolean().required(),
        role: Joi.number().valid(...Object.values(RoleModel)).optional(),
        password: Joi.string().required()
    })
```

I also wrote schema for student:

```
   public static StudentValidationSchema = Joi.object({
        phone2: Joi.string().optional().min(2).max(15),
        isWhatsapp2: Joi.boolean().optional(),
        address: Joi.string().required().min(2).max(15),
        school: Joi.string().required().min(2).max(15),
        birthDate: Joi.date().required(),
        level: Joi.number().valid(...Object.values(LevelModel)).optional().positive(),
        category: Joi.number().valid(...Object.values(CategoryModel)).optional(),
        subscriptions: Joi.number().optional().positive().default(1),
    })
```

now I wanna add the user schema to the student schema

for now I'm using that but I'm still looking for a better solution

```
    public StudentValidationSchema = Joi.object({
        userID: Joi.number().optional().positive(),
        firstName: Joi.string().required().min(2).max(15),
        lastName: Joi.string().required().min(2).max(15),
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        phone: Joi.string().required().min(10).max(13),
        isWhatsapp: Joi.boolean().required(),
        role: Joi.number().valid(...Object.values(RoleModel)).optional(),
        password: Joi.string().required(),

        
        phone2: Joi.string().optional().min(2).max(15),
        isWhatsapp2: Joi.boolean().optional(),
        address: Joi.string().required().min(2).max(15),
        school: Joi.string().required().min(2).max(15),
        birthDate: Joi.date().required(),
        level: Joi.number().valid(...Object.values(LevelModel)).optional().positive(),
        category: Joi.number().valid(...Object.values(CategoryModel)).optional(),
        subscriptions: Joi.number().optional().positive().default(1),
    })
```